# Arrow keys with cat / read

Tags: command-line, bash, input, text-mode

I want to read a line of text and be able to move the cursor left and right while editing.

When I call `cat` or use `read` in bash, and press arrow keys, I get `^[[A^[[B^[[C^[[D` istead of moving the cursor.

I use `bash` from `gnome-terminal` and `mate-terminal`, locally (no SSH).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to *@steeldriver*, I found a solution which allows moving cursor left/right and does not show bash history when pressing up/down arrows.

#### One way is to create a bash script

```
history -c          # clear history
read -ep "$*" var   # read value using readline,
                    #   display prompt supplied as argument
echo "$var"         # echo the value so it can be captured by the caller
```

Then call this script from another script or shell:

```
var=`readline 'value: '`
```

#### Another way is to create a function

This function can be defined to run in a subshell, making it essentially same as the above script:

```
readline() (
  history -c
  read -ep "$*" var
  echo "$var"
)
```

Or it can be executed directly in the current shell, in which case the history of the current shell must be saved prior to clearing it, and then restored:

```
readline() {
  history -w          # write current history to the $HISTFILE
  history -c          # ...
  read -ep "$*" var   # ... same as above
  echo "$var"         # ...
  history -r          # resotre history (read from $HISTFILE)
}
```

*However*, if you decide to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> while entering text, you will end up with no history, because the function will get interrupted before restoring the history.

The solution is to use traps. Set up a trap on INT signal which restores the history and then "untraps" the signal.

```
readline() {
  # set up a trap which restores history and removes itself
  trap "history -r; trap - SIGINT; return" SIGINT

  history -w
  history -c
  read -ep "$*" var
  echo "$var"
  history -r

  trap - SIGINT
}
```

*However*, if a trap is already set up on the INT signal, you would just discard it. So you have to save the already-existing trap, then set up a new one, do your business and then restore the old one.

```
readline() {
  local err=0 sigint_trap orig_trap

  sigint_trap=`trap -p | grep ' SIGINT$'`

  if [[ $sigint_trap ]]; then
    # A trap was already set up ‒ save it
    orig_trap=`sed 's/trap -- \(.*\) SIGINT$/\1/' <<<"$sigint_trap"`
  fi

  # Don't do anything upon receiving SIGINT (eg. user pressed Ctrl+C).
  # This is to prevent the function from exiting before it has restored
  # the original trap.
  trap ':' SIGINT

  # `read` must be called from a subshell, otherwise it will run
  # again and again when interrupted. This has something to do with
  # the fact that `read` is a shell builtin. Since `read` reads a value
  # into variable in a subshell, this variable won't exist in the parent
  # shell. And since a subshell is already used, the history might as well
  # be cleared in the subshell instead of the current shell ‒ then it's
  # not necessary to save and restore it. If this subshell returns a
  # non-zero value, the call to `read` was interrupted, and there will be
  # no output. However, no output does not indicate an interrupted read,
  # since the input could have been empty. That's why an exit code is
  # necessary ‒ to determine whether the read was interrupted.
  ( history -c
    read -ep "$*" var
    echo "$var"
  ) || {
    # `read` was interrupted ‒ save the exit code and echo a newline
    # to stderr (because stdin is captured by the caller).
    err=$?
    echo >&2
  }

  # The subshell can be replaced by a call to the above script:
  ## "`which readline`" "$@" || { err=$?; echo >&2; }

  if [[ $sigint_trap ]]; then
    # Restore the old trap
    trap "`eval echo "$orig_trap"`" SIGINT
  else
    # Remove trap
    trap - SIGINT
  fi

  # Return non-zero if interrupted, else zero
  return $err
}
```

So even though this last version is "slightly" more complex than the original one and still doesn't avoid starting a subshell, it provides an indication of whether the read was successful or not (which neither of the simpler versions does).

It can be used like so:

```
my_function() {
  ...
  message=`readline $'\e[1mCommit message:\e[m '` || {
    echo "[User abort]" >&2
    return 1
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: `HISTSIZE=0 read -rep "$*: " var` think it's because you are missing `#!/bin/bash`, your script will then inherit the history from your current shell, but I'm unsure. at least you can disable it with `HISTSIZE`.

Answer (score 4):

With the `read` builtin of the `bash` shell, you can use the `-e` option to enable readline support. From `help read`:

```
-e     use Readline to obtain the line in an interactive shell
```

For example

```
read -ep "Please enter some text: "
```

I'm not aware of any way to do that with a `cat` here-document.

Comment: This works, but I can not only move the cursor left and right, but also up, which shows previous commands typed in bash. Do you think it would be possible to disable bash history when using            `read -e`?

Comment: @kyrill Hmm... nothing comes to mind, but I'll have a think about that